# Fetch limited elements from a document

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have documents like -

```
<a:root xmlns:a = 'some-ns'>
    <a:id>some-id</a:id>
    .
    .
    <a:number field='field1'>3</a:number>
    <a:number field='field2'>4</a:number>
    .
    .
</a:root>
```

I do have the ids for the documents to fetch, I want to extract the `a:id` and `a:number` of all those documents which match the query **without using XPath**. 
I can easily get the document matching the id using a [`cts.elementValueQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementValueQuery) and then use XPath to get the elements. Something like this -

```
cts.search(  
  cts.andQuery(
    [
      cts.collectionQuery('liveCollection'),
      cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName(a, 'id'), 'http://iddn.icis.com/series/energy/cegh-day-ahead-index')      
    ]
  )
).next().value.getElementsByTagNameNS(a, 'number')
```

But I want MarkLogic to return only selected elements.

Can anyone please tell me the optimized way to do this?

I have written this query (Not giving me the expected result) -

```
cts.elementValueCoOccurrences(
  fn.QName(c, 'id'), 
  fn.QName(c, 'precision'), 
  ('map'),
  cts.andQuery(
      [
        cts.collectionQuery(liveCollection),
        cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName(c, 'id'), seriesIds)
      ]
    )
  )
```

I am looking to get an output like this -

|`<a:id>id-1</a:id>`|`<a:number field='field1'>3</a:number>`|

|`<a:id>id-1</a:id>`|`<a:number field='field2'>4</a:number>`|

|`<a:id>id-2</a:id>`|`<a:number field='field1'>3</a:number>`|

Comment: Can you show how the output is supposed to look, and what have you tried yourself?

Comment: @grtjn I have updated the question. Can you please suggest something now?

Answer (score 3):

That is a data modelling challenge in some ways. You do not want to filter your documents (xPath into them), but you only want part of the results back.

Even if you were to try to get fancy with he searchable expression, the default result is the first match, so you would still need to turn on filtered queries.

Unfortunately, the optimised way to do this is via range indexes... But once the indexes are in place, you could then use co-occurance to extract the id and numbers in a json result-set to then further process.